Force b/w current carrying loops
[
In the figure shown the rings are carrying currents in same sense. In this situation there is no interaction between them but if they were carrying current in opposite sense would they repel each other? If they dont then how does in the jumping ring experiment the ring leviates in air as the loops in the solenoid are similar to current carrying rings

When, at the start, the two loops are carrying current in the same direction, they are already pulling at each other. So, you are already wrong in saying that they are not interacting at the start.

Yes but this question came in jee Advnaced (indian engineering entrance exam) 2007 and in the answer it is given that there is no attraction between the loops and the logic i find every where in the internet is that force on a current carrying closed loop is zero in unifrom magnetic field


In the figure shown the rings are carrying currents in same sense. In this situation there is no interaction between them

This is false. If currents with the same intensity are in the same or the opposite directions, the interaction has the same intensity but opposite direction.
I'm giving you some mathematical details and a brief discussion of the results below. If you're not used to such a math, you can just skip them and trust the results with a small leap of faith (math here should be ok), and go to the brief discussion.
Some details
The elementary force acting on a elementary wire of length $d \ell(\mathbf{r})$ pointing in direction $\mathbf{\hat{t}}$ carrying current $i$ at a point in space $\mathbf{r}$, immersed in a magnetic field $\mathbf{b}(\mathbf{r})$ is
$$d \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r}) = - i(\mathbf{r}) \, \mathbf{b}(\mathbf{r}) \times d \boldsymbol{\ell}(\mathbf{r}) \ .$$
The elementary magnetic field produced in $\mathbf{r}$ by a current density $\mathbf{j}(\mathbf{r}_0)$ in an elementary volume $dV_0$ in $\mathbf{r}_0$ is (something useful for a "proof" in wiki page)
$$d \mathbf{b}(\mathbf{r}) = - \frac{\mu}{4\pi} \frac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_0}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_0|^3} \times \mathbf{j}(\mathbf{r}_0) dV_0 \ ,$$
and thus, the magnetic field produced by an elementary wire is
$$d \mathbf{b}(\mathbf{r}) = - \frac{\mu}{4\pi} \frac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_0}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_0|^3} \times \mathbf{\hat{t}}(\mathbf{r}_0) i(\mathbf{r}_0) d\ell_0 \ .$$
Thus, the magnetic field produced by the current $i_2$ in the circuit $2$ on the points $\mathbf{r}_1$ of the circuit $1$ can be evaluated by means of integration over $\ell_2$
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{b}_{12}(\mathbf{r}_1) & = \int_{\mathbf{r}_2\in\ell_2} d \mathbf{b}_{12}(\mathbf{r}_1) = \\
& = - i_2 \frac{\mu}{4\pi}\int_{\mathbf{r}_2\in\ell_2} \frac{\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2}{|\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2|^3} \times \mathbf{\hat{t}}_2(\mathbf{r}_2) d\ell_2
\end{aligned}$$
and the force produced on circuit $1$ by circuit $2$ can be evaluated by means of integration
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{F}_{12} & = \int_{\mathbf{r}_1 \in \ell_1} d \mathbf{F}_{12}(\mathbf{r}_1) = \\
& =  i_1 \int_{\mathbf{r}_1 \in \ell_1} \mathbf{b}_{12}(\mathbf{r}_1) \times \mathbf{\hat{t}}_1(\mathbf{r}_1) d \ell_1 = \\
& = - i_1 \, i_2 \int_{\mathbf{r}_1 \in \ell_1} \int_{\mathbf{r}_1 \in \ell_2} \left( \frac{\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2}{|\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2|^3} \times \mathbf{\hat{t}}_2(\mathbf{r}_2) \right) \times \mathbf{\hat{t}}_1(\mathbf{r}_1) d \ell_1 d \ell_2 \ .
\end{aligned}$$
Discussion
In the expression of the force $\mathbf{F}_{12}$, the double integral only depends on the geometry of the problem,
$$\mathbf{F}_{12} = i_1 \, i_2 \, G_{12} \ .$$
You can easily realize that if you change the sign of a current, the sign of the force changes as well.

Can you please tell me how the magnetic field lines associated with the with two rings look like when the current is in the same direction and when it is opposite

The sources of the currents in your diagram are unclear.
Firstly suppose they are from two batteries.
If the currents are flowing in the same direction there is a magnetic interaction between the two rings and the rings will attract one another.
If the current in one of the rings is reversed then there will be a repulsive force between the rings.
Now consider a steady current in one of the rings which will result in no interaction between the rings.
However, if the current in the left-hand ring is increasing then this will result in an induced emf in the right-hand ring (Faraday).
If the right-hand ring is continuous and a conductor then the induced emf in the right-hand ring will produce an induced current in the right-hand ring.
That induced current in the right-hand ring will oppose the change in magnetic flux produced by the left-hand ring (Lenz) and there will be repulsion between the rings which is the situation in the jumping ring demonstration.
Another way of thinking about the jumping ring is that the ring carrying the induced current is trying to get further away from the the ring producing the changing magnetic field because the magnetic field gets weaker further away from a source and hence the change in magnetic flux will be smaller.

-1? As always I would value a reason for the downgrade.
